# pass value from jsp to servlet using <a href>

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, href

I have jsp page  -

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
      <a href="http://localhost:8080/MyProject/Servlet123?usrID=33333">Go to servlet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And servlet -

```
@WebServlet("/Servlet123")
public class Servlet123 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // take the ID and retrive all his accounts..
        String usrID = request.getAttribute("usrID").toString();
          }

}
```

When I press on the link in the jsp page  , it throws exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in the line  -  `String usrID = request.getAttribute("usrID").toString();`

Other details - I use Apache Tomcat 7.0 Tomcat7 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getParameter()` instead of `getAttribute()`.